# flutter error - The argument type 'List<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Country>?'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a beginner in flutter, I am working on existing code.
I use the intl_phone_field package | Flutter Package to validate a phone number depending on the country.

However, the console shows me this error:

> The argument type `List<String>` can't be assigned to the parameter type `List<Country>?`.

I'll give you an image capture. Please guide me

How do I correct this error? I've been struggling for 1 week

Comment: please add full code.

Comment: IntlPhoneField(
                          countries: countries.map((e) {
                            return e.code != "AM" ? e.code : "";
                          }).toList(),

Comment: add a full screen code its just a logic..

Comment: [edit] your question to include code that is as small as possible while still reproducing the error

Comment: please how to add the whole code here?

Comment: edit you question to add code @dibase

Answer (score 0):

```
IntlPhoneField(
                      countries: countries.map((e) {
                        return e.code != "AM" ? e.code : "";
                      }).toList(),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: '',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: isDarkMode
                                  ? AppColors.borderDark
                                  : AppColors.borderColor),
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: isDarkMode
                                  ? AppColors.borderDark
                                  : AppColors.borderColor),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: isDarkMode
                                  ? AppColors.borderDark
                                  : AppColors.borderColor),
                        ),
                      ),
                      initialCountryCode: 'UZ',
                      onChanged: (phone) {
                        notifier.setEmail(phone.completeNumber);
                      },
                    ),
```

[image capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Xw4.png)

Comment: How to do it as a beginner?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
create this method above the build context

```
      List<Country> getSelectedCountries() {
    List<String> countryCodes = countries.map((e) {
      return e.code != "AM" ? e.code : "";
    }).toList();

    return countries.where((country) {
      return !countryCodes.contains(country.code);
    }).toList();
  }
```

then call inside the build context like this

```
.....

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Country> selectedCountries = getSelectedCountries();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(  .....
```

then use the `selectedCountries` in `countries:`

eg.

```
 IntlPhoneField(
                focusNode: focusNode,
                countries: selectedCountries,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Phone Number',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(),
                  ),
                ),
               ),
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Well it worked, I no longer have any errors. Great, you saved my life @Karishma Nadar

Comment: Happy to help! if this has solved please do mark the Question as Solved.

Answer (score 0):

The countries property of IntlPhoneField get a list of Country with the possibility for values to be null (List< Country >?), by providing e.code you're assigning a String instead of a Country.

I assume that *countries* is a List of country, instead of *e.code* you should just put *e*

I can see that you want to exclude Armenia which has code "AM" so instead of putting an empty String, you can just put null.

To fix that, you should replace that part with:

```
countries: countries.map((e) {
    return e.code != "AM" ? e : null;
}).toList(),
```